# unable to connect to cache daemon?

Tags: git

I am able to push fine, but I am suddenly getting this "fatal" message

```
$ git push
fatal: unable to connect to cache daemon: Bad file descriptor
Username for 'https://github.com':
Password for 'https://myid@github.com':
fatal: unable to connect to cache daemon: Bad file descriptor
...
```

Why do I get this message all of the sudden? and what do I do?

I am not sure this might help, but between now and before this problem occurred

- I was working on some branch that is not master
- I changed my user.email in git config --global in the middle
- my computer crashed big time because I connected the wrong project connector(that is not for the computer) to it, and I believe somehow some file got corrupted
- After that occurred, when I tried to make a new commit,I was getting the following message : fatal: Failed to resolve HEAD as a valid ref.
- Then I fixed it by modifying HEAD in config to "ref: refs/heads/master"
- After coding and successfully committing the changes locally,  when I tried to push it to the remote server, I got the following error message

  $ git push

  fatal: unable to connect to cache daemon: Bad file descriptor
  Username for 'https://github.com':
  Password for 'https://myid0@github.com':
  fatal: unable to connect to cache daemon: Bad file descriptor
  fatal: loose object 8ce710b1c78658e066cd2309b12b7766d1be4920 (stored in     .git/objects/8c/e710b1c78658e066cd2309b12b7766d1be4920) is corrupt
  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
  fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor
- So I backed up all the changes I made, deleted the repo, clone the repo from the github, and made some changes with the backup files, add, commit, and pushed the changes fine...but still that message does not go away :(

Comment: I have  colleague who gets a very similar error, except instead of "bad file descriptor", he sees "permission denied".  But the push works, so "fatal" is obviously not fatal.

Answer (score 37):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14160580

solved this for me:

```
sudo chown kev ~/.git-credential-cache/socket
```

replace kev with your user if you don't know your user:

```
whoami
```

Comment: `chown: cannot access ‘/home/butko/.git-credential-cache/socket’: No such file or directory` :/ But my error says: `fatal: unable to connect to cache daemon: Permission denied`

Comment: On recent versions of Linux (e.g. Ubuntu 18), as mentioned by Alwaysimproving below and also here -- https://gist.github.com/diegopacheco/ca7aeb7f6ce283d7d13b710f5301e969 -- this is the command that works: `sudo chown $(whoami) ~/.cache/git/credential/socket`

Answer (score 11):

Beware of manipulating `~/.git-credential-cache/socket` (as with `chown`), for it has moved since 2014, as acknowledge by Git 2.13 (Q2 2017)
[Adam K Dean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1138620/adam-k-dean) also mention [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779007/unable-to-connect-to-cache-daemon/43355775?noredirect=1#comment102224574_43355775) the path `~/.cache/git/credential/`, which just needed chowning back to the user.

See [commit 612c49e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/612c49e94d5c761bd9fc4752283b82786c23856a), [commit 60759ba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/60759baac1f063a6c3069ca4b909abb8a20fa08a) (17 Mar 2017), and [commit e7f136b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e7f136bf93132c24183c168a9a054540e6216c06) (13 Mar 2017) by [Devin Lehmacher (`lehmacdj`)](https://github.com/lehmacdj).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 78cf8ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/78cf8efec34c419ecea86bc8d1fe47ec0b51ba37), 24 Mar 2017)</sup>

> ### credential-cache: use `XDG_CACHE_HOME` for socket

> Make `git-credential-cache` follow the **[XDG base path specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)** by
> default. This **increases consistency with other applications and helps
> keep clutter out of users' home directories**.

> Check the old socket location, `~/.git-credential-cache/`, and use
> `~/.git-credential-cache/socket` if that directory exists rather than
> forcing users who have used `git credential-cache` before to migrate to
> the new XDG compliant location.

> Otherwise use the socket `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/git/credential/socket` following
> XDG base path specification.
> Use the subdirectory `credential/` in case
> other files are cached under `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/git/` in the future and to
> make the socket's purpose clear.

---

Note: With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), a handful of places in in-tree code still relied on being able to execute the [`git`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/18aff08e04502c565e9a0538df12d04f2ca8765c/Documentation/git.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git))</sup> subcommands, especially built-ins, in "**`git-foo`**" form, which have been corrected.

See [commit c0e190c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0e190c168becfd7d6c27cd868542295bd474742), [commit 7cff3b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7cff3b67aca11f757fb36ac58a89ae54bcb5b19e), [commit 675df19](https://github.com/git/git/commit/675df192c5fad6a2b35ea43d4017b01e275eddef) (26 Aug 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 18aff08](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18aff08e04502c565e9a0538df12d04f2ca8765c), 03 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`credential-cache`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0e190c168becfd7d6c27cd868542295bd474742): use `child_process.args`

> As `child_process` structure has an embedded `strvec args` for formulating the command line, let's use it instead of using an out-of-line `argv[]` whose length needs to be maintained correctly.
>
> Also, when spawning a `git` subcommand, omit it from the command list and instead use the `.git_cmd` bit in the `child_process` structure.

So, no more call to `git-credential-cache--daemon`, but rather `git credential-cache--daemon`.

Comment: In my case, the path was `~/.cache/git/credential/` which just needed chowning back to the user.

Comment: @AdamKDean Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 4):

> This error comes when you try to commit using "sudo". 
>   so the password saved is for "sudo" user only,
>   
>   But when you try to commit as a normal user, 
>   This error happens, permission denied for normal user
>   you can get rid of this error by using above answer Kev Price

Answer (score 2):

**Quick solution**

Here is the single command you need to solve the issue.

```
sudo chown $(whoami) ~/.cache/git/credential/socket
```

Read the other answers if you want a deeper understanding of what causes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set global gitconfig.

```
git config --global user.name "your username"
git config --global user.email "your email address"
```

Comment: try explaining why your answer is helpful

Comment: how is this answer related to the question ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to your first setup as root user, and then you want to use git as another user.You can change the git cache permission:

chown -R user:user_group ~/.cache/git/