# Git fatal: cache daemon did not start

Tags: linux, git, github

I am receiving the error

```
git push jhaase1 master
fatal: unable to bind to '~/.git-credential-cache/socket': Operation not permitted
fatal: cache daemon did not start:
fatal: unable to bind to '~/.git-credential-cache/socket': Operation not permitted
fatal: cache daemon did not start:
Everything up-to-date
```

However, this is not an ownership issue like in other posts I have [looked at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145783/git-pull-permission-denied-linux/14160580#14160580)

```
$ cd ~
$ ls -la
total 174
drwx------  42 jhaase1 campus  4096 Oct 12 14:20 .
drwx------   2 root    root    8192 Sep 26 09:15 ..
-rw-------   1 jhaase1 campus 11280 Sep 21 08:20 .ICEauthority
drwxr-xr-x  10 jhaase1 campus  2048 Oct 29  2014 .Mathematica
-rw-------   1 jhaase1 campus 10470 Oct 12 14:20 .Xauthority
-rw-------   1 jhaase1 campus   455 Jun  4  2012 .Xauthority_tmp
drwxr-xr-x   6 jhaase1 campus  2048 Aug 12 19:55 .allinea
lrwxr-xr-x   1 jhaase1 campus    14 May 21  2012 .bashrc -> Public/.bashrc
-rw-------   1 jhaase1 campus  8160 Oct  6  2015 .bash_history
lrwxr-xr-x   1 jhaase1 campus    19 May 21  2012 .bash_logout -> Public/.bash_logout
lrwxr-xr-x   1 jhaase1 campus    20 May 21  2012 .bash_profile -> Public/.bash_profile
drwxr-xr-x   6 jhaase1 campus  2048 Jun 22 17:01 .cache
drwxr-xr-x   6 jhaase1 campus  2048 Jun 14 18:01 .comsol
drwx------  11 jhaase1 campus  2048 Sep 23 23:12 .config
lrwxr-xr-x   1 jhaase1 campus    13 May 21  2012 .cshrc -> Public/.cshrc
drwx------   3 jhaase1 campus  2048 May 28  2013 .dbus
-rw-r--r--   1 jhaase1 campus   592 Jul 16  2012 .emacs
drwxr-xr-x   3 jhaase1 campus  2048 May 25  2012 .emacs.d
-rw-r--r--   1 jhaase1 campus   308 Aug 30 12:41 .emacs-places
-rw-------   1 jhaase1 campus    16 Jun 16 17:11 .esd_auth
drwxr-xr-x   4 jhaase1 campus  2048 Jun 22 16:59 .fastx_server
drwxr-xr-x 157 jhaase1 campus 12288 May 17 18:08 .felix
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jhaase1 campus    73 Dec  3  2012 .flexlmrc
drwx------   3 jhaase1 campus  2048 Jul 29 12:11 .fltk
drwxr-xr-x   2 jhaase1 campus  2048 Jun 21 15:28 .fontconfig
drwx------   5 jhaase1 campus  2048 Oct 12 12:41 .gconf
drwx------   2 jhaase1 campus  2048 Oct 12 12:42 .gconfd
-rw-r--r--   1 jhaase1 campus    79 Oct 12 10:52 .gitconfig
drwx------   2 jhaase1 campus  2048 Sep 21 23:10 .git-credential-cache
drwx------   7 jhaase1 campus  2048 Jun 20 11:25 .gnome2
drwx------   2 jhaase1 campus  2048 May 25  2012 .gnome2_private
drwxr-xr-x   2 jhaase1 campus  2048 Nov  6  2013 .gstreamer-0.10
-rw-r--r--   1 jhaase1 campus     0 Aug  6  2013 .gtk-bookmarks
drwx------   2 jhaase1 campus  2048 Jun 16 17:11 .gvfs
-rw-------   1 jhaase1 campus  5085 Oct 11 23:03 .history
drwxr-xr-x   2 jhaase1 campus  2048 Jun 17 15:34 .icons
-rw-r--r--   1 jhaase1 campus 15690 Sep 21 08:29 .imsettings.log
drwxr-xr-x   4 jhaase1 campus  2048 Sep 16 21:45 .local
lrwxr-xr-x   1 jhaase1 campus    13 May 21  2012 .login -> Public/.login
-rw-r--r--   1 jhaase1 campus   166 Dec  3  2012 .maple_history
drwxr-xr-x  14 jhaase1 campus  2048 May 17 11:41 .matlab
drwxr-xr-x   2 jhaase1 campus  2048 Aug 13  2012 .memscape
-rw-r--r--   1 jhaase1 campus   375 Oct  3 12:36 .moose-profile
drwxr-xr-x   5 jhaase1 campus  2048 Sep  7  2015 .mozilla
drwxr-xr-x   2 jhaase1 campus  2048 Aug 18  2014 .nautilus
drwxr-----   3 jhaase1 campus  2048 Oct 20  2014 .pki
drwx------   2 jhaase1 campus  2048 Jun 22 17:00 .pulse
-rw-------   1 jhaase1 campus   256 Sep  5  2014 .pulse-cookie
drwxr-xr-x   2 jhaase1 campus  2048 Jun  1  2012 .qt
-rw-------   1 jhaase1 campus   589 Jun  4 17:14 .smpd
drw-------   2 jhaase1 campus  2048 Jan  6  2016 .ssh
drwxr-xr-x   3 jhaase1 campus  2048 Nov 13  2014 .subversion
drwxr-xr-x   2 jhaase1 campus  2048 Jun 17 15:34 .themes
drwx------   4 jhaase1 campus  2048 Jun 17 15:34 .thumbnails
drwx------   4 jhaase1 campus  2048 Jul 17  2012 .totalview
drwxr-xr-x   5 jhaase1 campus  2048 Sep 20 17:03 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x   4 jhaase1 campus  2048 Sep  1  2015 Documents
drwxr-xr-x   3 jhaase1 campus  2048 Jul 18 22:52 Downloads
drw-------   2 jhaase1 campus  2048 Jun  4  2012 Public
drwxr-xr-x 100 root    root    4096 Dec 31  1969 YESTRDAY
drwxr-xr-x   7 jhaase1 campus  2048 Oct 12 13:03 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 jhaase1 campus  2048 Dec 20  2013 intel
drwxr-xr-x   4 jhaase1 campus  2048 Oct  3 09:43 moose-base
drw-------   6 jhaase1 campus  2048 Oct  3 13:52 private
lrwxr-xr-x   1 jhaase1 campus    48 Oct  5 19:01 zapdos -> ~/moose-base/zapdos
```

Anything else I can try?