# git credential-cache/socket operation not permitted

Tags: git, credentials

I git cloned my own repo onto a server. Whenever I do git push, git pull or something, it keeps asking me username and password. Therefore, I enabled the global credential storage, and I did find everything setup under ~/.gitconfig. It should cache my username and password the first time I enter them, but it says

```
fatal: unable to bind to '/home/<myusername>/.git-credential-cache/socket': Operation not permitted

fatal: cache daemon did not start:
```

I don't have sudo to the server. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If this is not a [permission issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14160580/6309), you should try another credential helper, like the [GNOME Keyring](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2016/11/21/gnome-keyring-git-credential-helper/)

```
sudo apt install libgnome-keyring-dev
git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring/git-credential-gnome-keyring
```

Since you don't have sudo, check first if libgnome-keyring is not *already* installed. (`which gnome-keyring`)